# Selection input for QGIS Processing models

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, parameters, qgis-modeler

QGIS 2.14.11 LTR. In a processing script we can define a selection as input parameter by `##auswahl_test=selection spam;egg;dummy` resulting in

[image]

Background is, that I want to provide a selection of formulas (strings) as input for `field calculator` algorithm used in a model. By now, I'm typing these formulas in a string input field by hand, which is annoying, time-consuming and error-prone.

Now is there a way to obtain such input field in the auto-generated gui of a processing model? Or any other suggestions of how to provide a selection of strings as a model input?

Comment: May you post an example of formula?

Comment: It does't not matter in this context, since my issue is about selection from any set of strings, but as an input for field calculator, a formula might be something like `if("field2" is null, "field1", "field1"||' '"field2")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more of a workaround as I'm not sure if it's possible at the moment to allow a user to select from a range of string values. Instead, you could use **booleans** which would represent your formulae (these would be connected to a **custom script** which will contain your formulae). So that when a user clicks on a boolean from the modeler, the script will output the relevant formula to the **field calculator**.

---

Here is an example custom script where the inputs are three booleans and depending on which is selected, the `output string` will contain the formula. The formulae are very simple, multiplying values from the `id` field with an integer:

```
##Example=name
##formula_1=boolean
##formula_2=boolean
##formula_3=boolean
##selected_formula=output string

if formula_1 == True:
    selected_formula=""" "id" * 2 """
if formula_2 == True:
    selected_formula=""" "id" * 3 """
if formula_3 == True:
    selected_formula=""" "id" * 4 """
else:
    pass
```

Now in your modeler, create the **three booleans** (I would leave them unchecked as default). Then add your **custom script** linking the booleans. Then add your **field calculator**, and for your `Formula` parameter, choose the `'selected formula' from algorithm 'Example'`:

[image: Example modeler]

Now when you run your model, it should look something like the following where you can select the formula to be used:

[image: Running model]

Comment: It's far for me criticizing your awesome workaround, but this means adding a boolean to the model for each new formula... On the other hand, this was really inspiring to me, and pointed me to another one (see below)

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround just came out of my brain, since in models we can *select from table fields*. So my workaroud goes like this:

I put my formula collection in a nice spreadsheet, with i.e. a description of what the formulae do as headers:

[image]

This I add to my project.

Since I cannot pass table field values as input to `field calculator`, I have a tiny custom script, that makes strings of table field values:

```
##input=table
##a=field input
##text=output string
formeln=processing.getObject(input)
for fo in formeln.getFeatures():
    text = fo[a]
```

In my model, I have as input parameters a `table`, a `table field` and a `vector`, passing `table` and `table field` to the custom script, and passing its output to the `field calculator`:

[image]

In the resulting gui, I can now select from the descriptions of my formulae (doing so, variety of different formula collections would be thinkable):

[image]

Comment: Now that is a very, _very_ clever workaround. Kudos to you! I'm now curious as to what your  _secret formula_ is :)