# How to make a database to be a model parameter in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, import, database, qgis-modeler

I built  a model in QGIS that imports vector into PostGIS database. My only problem is that I can choose which database I would like to import my data into but only if I rightclick on the model and edit it. (There is a drop-down list and I can choose.)

Is there a way to make it to be a model parameter (drop-down list) so that it won't be neccesary to edit the model every time I would like to choose a different database for the model?

Comment: I don't think this is possible at the moment as the modeler doesn't have a _database_ input parameter. A lousy workaround could be to create a csv file containing your database names (as described [in this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229435/selection-input-for-qgis-processing-models/229494#229494)) where they can be seleced from the modeler GUI. And replace your `Imports vector into PostGIS database` algorithm with a **custom script** which reads the selected input and runs the same algorithm. In my opinion, _right-click > edit_ is a lot easier :)

Comment: Do you mean export your data in Post GIS?